# google code check out

Tags: android, tortoisesvn, google-checkout

Trying to get a local copy of mytracks from:
[mytracks google code source](http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/checkout)

I have installed Tortoise SVN but it's throwing the error:

```
error server sent unexpected return value (405 method not allowed)
```

I have no idea what to do with this, can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: what is your checkut command?

Comment: you know that is not an SVN repo, right? Clone it using `hg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyTracks has a Mercurial repository, not a Subversion one, as can be seen by the following message at the bottom of the checkout page:

> This project's **Mercurial** repository
>   may be accessed using many different
>   client programs and plug-ins. See your
>   client's documentation for more
>   information.

You'll want to use Tortoise HG for this:
http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/